# Undefined control sequence error when using combine class

Tags: combine

I am trying to Combine (6) .tex documents into one document. Have tried several 'combine' templates but nothing works. This is my current main document attempt.

```
\documentclass[book]{combine}
\title{Pepperdine Papers on LTL}
\author{J. Stanley Warford, David Vega, Scott M. Staley}
\date{today}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{combine}         % use the combine page style
\maketitle          % main title 
\tableofcontents        % main ToC 
\clearpage

\section{Editor’s introduction} 
Here is where the introduction will be written
\label{Introduction}            % into main ToC (section 1)


\begin{papers}
    \coltoctitle{A Calculational Deductive System for Linear Temporal Logic}
    \coltocauthor{J. Stanley Warford, David Vega, Scott M. Staley}
    \label{eds4ltl-paper-copy}
    \include{eds4ltl-paper-copy}     

    \coltoctitle{Vega Paper}
    \coltocauthor{J. Stanley Warford, David Vega, Scott M. Staley}
    \label{Vega-Paper-copyFontsChanged}
    \include{Vega-Paper-copyFontsChanged}
\end{papers}

\clearpage
\section{Acknowledgements}
Here is where the Acknowledgments and Prologue will be written.

\end{document}
```

**Here is the current error code I am getting:**

> eds4ltl-paper-copy.tex    9  Undefined control sequence. \leqnomode
>   ->\tagsleft@true 
>                                l.9 \leqnomode

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The files `eds4ltl-paper-copy.tex` and `Vega-Paper-copyFontsChanged` are not provided. If I comment those lines out, then the document compiles without an error code on LaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaTeX.

Comment: Yes, for my first attempt I put in simpler .tex docs with minimal preambles, etc. and it typeset fine.  Then when I imported my first two documents - error message.

Comment: I will attach the two .tex files here.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AozX3u0dOxgJr1vv_iFAIqaPAkw1?e=UxMcLs

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AozX3u0dOxgJsCpVk8I7ATlmeTnY?e=i2CzFY